# Convert USB to WiFi Printer

Tags: usb, wifi, server, ethernet, printer

I've tried to convert my USB ESC/POS printer to a network printer. I have tried print servers such as the TL-WPS510U, but it only supports PS and PCL. Is there a print server that supports ESC/POS?

If not, is there anyway that I could convert my USB to network printer?

Alternatively, I could purchase Ethernet printer. <del>Is there a way to convert Ethernet printer to WiFi printer?</del> Can anyone recommend hardware that is available to allow Ethernet printer to function as a WiFi printer?

Comment: Welcome to Hardware Recommendations! I've closed this question because it's asking us for technical support. Remember that we can't do troubleshooting, tech support or compatibility queries. If your question isn't any of those, please clarify exactly what hardware you're looking for, and make sure your question focuses on the hardware recommendation rather than the tech support.

Comment: LOL... really? did you read the question "Is there any print server that support ESC/POS". I was surely, utterly, 100% asking for hardware recommendation. How could you miss-understand it? Amazing...

Comment: No, I closed this question because its primary function seems to be "is there a way to convert...".

Comment: LOL... you are very picky on wording... OK, I apologise. I wasn't used a right words to ask a question. I have modified my questions. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not look like there are any companies currently making a USB-to-wifi print server that supports ESC/P. Viewsonic made one years ago (model WPS-100), but it only supported wireless G and its configuration software was made for Windows XP. In other words, even if you could track one of these down, it would likely have compatibility issues.

Alternatively, if you have a printer with ethernet access, you can get a wireless access point and set it to bridge mode. After this access point is configured in bridge mode you'll be able to plug an ethernet cable between your printer and the access point. At this point your printer should be available on your wireless network.